# Mp3 audio file is playing in android but not able to play in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am downloading audio file which is in mp3 format from dot net(.net) webservice to documents folder,but i am not able to play it,but the same audio file is playing in android phone when it is downloaded,what could be the reason

Comment: Give some code you have tried.

Comment: Are you sure it's an mp3 and not some other format (e.g. wma) just named .mp3?

Comment: yes.. send the code you tried then we can tell

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your android phone has a codec which your iPhone does not support.
Installing a different media player might work